# Постраничный вывод на PHP из MySql

Tags: постраничный-вывод, php, mysql

Написал скриптик для постраничного вывода:

```
function pages($param) {
 $page_tmpl = ''; // объявляем переменную page_tmpl для использования return
 $pages_count = ceil($param['ents_count'] / $param['ents_print']);
 for($i = 1; $i <= $pages_count; $i++) {
  if($i == $param['page'] || !$param['page'] && $i == 1) $page_tmpl .=  '<b>'.$i.'</b> ';
  else $page_tmpl .= '<a href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> ';
  if($i != $pages_count) $page_tmpl .= '';
 }
 return $page_tmpl;
}

(!intval($_GET['page'])) ? $start_page = 0 : $start_page = $_GET['page'] - 1;

// выводим из таблицы support данные
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `support` LIMIT $start_page, 2");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
 echo $data['qid'].'<hr />';
}

// выводим переключатели страниц
// 'ents_print' => 2 - сколько материалов отображать
// 'ents_count' => 5 - сколько всего материалов в таблице support
echo pages(array('page' => $_GET['page'], 'ents_print' => 2, 'ents_count' => 5));
```

Так вот. Получается кривой вывод. Должно

> Первая страница: 1 и 2
>
> Вторая страница 3 и 4
>
> Третья страница 5 и 6

А сейчас:

> Первая страница: 1 и 2
>
> Вторая страница 2 и 3
>
> Третья страница 3 и 4

http://montytool.ru/system/modules/support/pages.php вот ссылка на реализацию.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А почитать про параметр LIMIT у MySQL не судьба?

```
LIMIT start, count
```

Т.е. надо так:

```
$start = $start_page * $param['ents_print'];
$limit = $param['ents_print'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `support` LIMIT $start, $limit");
```

Comment: @Photon, благодарю.